# Allow dropdown content to stay outside of nav bar

Tags: html, css

This is probably abominably obvious to everyone, but I am very new to HTML. How would I allow my webpage to start from the very top and very left, rather than ~10px after, while using `position:relative`?

Comment: Have you given `html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, browsers put an 8px margin on `body`. To counter this, you'll need to add `body { margin: 0; }` to your stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Will accept it in 7 minutes when it lets me. :)